# generate botton for each information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am pulling some information from an external database using javascript. However, I am not sure how to generate a like unlike toggle button for users to click below each information.

I place a toggle link within the appendeddata variable just to test if it would work. The link did show up below each data but the toggle effect did not work. I place the code within the same script and in its own script however no luck.

I want to also id the user that clicks the link. how can I do this?

Thank you.

here is my javascript code.

```
   var appendedhtml = "";
   var address = "";


   function getDomes() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://api.google.com/d/domes/explore? 
    ll="+lat+","+lng+"&client_id= client_id&query="+$("#query").val()+"",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#domes").show();
                var dataobj = data.response.groups[0].items;
                $("#domes").html("");

                $.each( dataobj, function() {
                    if (this.dome.categories[0]) {
                        str = this.dome.categories[0].icon.prefix;
                        newstr = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
                        icon = newstr+this.dome.categories
                        [0].icon.suffix;
                    } else {
                        icon = "";
                    }


                    if (this.dome.location.address) {
                        address = '<p 
                   class="subinfo">'+this.dome.location.address+'<br>';
                    } else {
                        address = "";
                    }

                    appendedtml = '<div 
      class="venue"><h2><span>'+address'</span></h2><a href="#" class="toggler">&nbsp;</a><hr>';
                    $("#domes").append(appendedhtml);


                });
            }
        });
    }
```

I place the code that would give the toggle effect within the main script and by itself
      with no luck.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('a.toggler').click(function(){
       $(this).toggleClass('off');
    });
});
```

this is the css for the toggle button. I know the button works indecently just cannot get it
   to work with the data output from the main script.

```
a.toggler {
         background: green;
         cursor: pointer;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-right-width: 15px;
        padding: 0 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: all .5s ease;
    }

a.toggler.off {
    background: red;
    border-right-width: 2px;
    border-left-width: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try jQuery's [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead of click method.

```
$( "a.toggler" ).on( "click", function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('off');
});
```

`on` method listens to events from elements that were created dynamically.

Comment: it worked but its every other toggle not all the toggles buttons

Comment: @jack if you could provide me a Fiddle with of your problem, then I'll have a look at it. Actually, I made small Fiddle with three <a> elements in it and the toggle worked fine, but I'm confused what you mean by ever other toggle. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/oqr7h36w/1/ If you mean every second toggle button should work in toggle style, then you could add separate classes for those buttons. Anyway you had some cool styles for your toggle buttons :-)

Comment: No it is not separate toggle buttons it is just one button being generated multiple time within the appendedhtml variable. so when the program runs that one button appears below every data. This is very similar to facebook comment section or like button. However, at position one the button works and at position two the button don't work. then is I refresh at position two the button works then at position one the button does not work.